# lookup field should not required while update but required while create

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using model viewset in django rest framework.
where lookup field is *company*

```
    class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        """
        A viewset for viewing and editing user instances.
        """
        serializer_class = UserSerializer
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        lookup_field = 'company'
```

*Company* is required when create user.
POST method - /localhost/user/

but when i trying to update 
PUT method - /localhost/user/1/
here 1 is company_id

it is raising error

```
    {
        "company": [
            "This field is required."
        ]
    }
```

serializers.py

```
    class UserSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = "__all__"
```

If i make *company*  allow_null =True 
then it will also not required for create metod.

How can i make **company** required for create.

and 
*not required* for update

Comment: Can you show `User` model ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge User model is same as djagno's default user model only 
foreign key company is added there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PUT` method is update,it's need you upload all your model fields data,
`PATCH` method is partial_update,it's only need you upload partial model fields data.

View the source code you will see:

```
def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['partial'] = True
    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    instance = self.get_object()
    self.before_update(instance)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
    ....
```

`partial=partial` is what matters,or you need `PATCH` method - `/localhost/user/1/`